# how do I get my background image to change every time the mouse moves using the onmousemove function?

Tags: javascript, image, background, onmousemove

I would like my background image to change every time the mouse is moved. How would I go about doing this .

Comment: This is more than one question, so it should be broken down. You need to know how to programmatically set the image, and how to activate it when your mouse moves.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="background" src="" onmouseover="next()">

<script>

var picNum = 3;
//number of pictures you have
var picSrc = ["pic1Src", "pic2Src", "pic3Src"];
//provide url for each picture or directory for each
var currentPic = 1;
//initialize var for pic number

next(){

var obj = document.getElementById('background');
//Set obj to background
obj.src = picSrc[currentPic];
//Set obj's source to currentPic

var currentPic = currentPic + 1 % picNum
//Increases currentPic by one for next time, however if it goes over the         number of pics you have, it goes back to zero.

}
</script>
```

Comment: If you used the background code instead of img, take the id="background" and onmouseover="next()" there and forget the img.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the background image as each mousemove event. The image could not be loaded fast enough.

I used css3 animations (with -webkit prefix only, adapt to your browser if needed). Animation is triggered only if the mouse is moving. See code below  and this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8mx1Lgu/)

```
<html>
  <head>
      <style>
          body{
           background:linear-gradient(90deg, #FF4E50 10%, #F9D423 90%); 
          }

          body.mouseMove{

            -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

            -webkit-animation-name: bg-change;
          }

          @-webkit-keyframes bg-change {
            0% {background:linear-gradient(90deg, #24C6DC 10%, #514A9D 90%); }
            30% { background:linear-gradient(90deg, #FF4E50 10%, #F9D423 90%);}
            60% {background:linear-gradient(90deg, #B3FFAB 10%, #12FFF7 90%);}
            100% {background:linear-gradient(90deg, #24C6DC 10%, #514A9D 90%); }
          }

      </style>
    </head>
  <body>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          var body= document.querySelector("body");

          var endMoveTimeout;
          body.addEventListener('mousemove',function(){
            clearTimeout(endMoveTimeout);
            body.classList.add("mouseMove");
            endMoveTimeout= setTimeout(function(){
              body.classList.remove("mouseMove");
            },1000);
          });


          body.addEventListener('animationiteration',function(e){
            console.log(e);
          });

      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```